# Dockerize Angular app while managing environments

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have an Angular app which makes use of different environments. I have defined my environment files in the environments folder (`environment.int.ts`, `environment.test.ts`, `environment.prod.ts`). Then I have modified my `angular.json` file with my environments settings, for example:

```
"test" : {
    "fileReplacements": [
     {
         "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
         "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
     }
  ]
},
```

and I have created custom commands in my `package.json` to run them:

```
"build-prod": "ng build --prod",
"build-test": "ng build --configuration=test",
"build-int": "ng build --configuration=int",
```

Now I aim to dockerize my app, build it (by choosing the environment) and run it in a container.

Therefore I have created multiple `docker-compose.yml` files for each environment (`docker-compose-int.yml`, `docker-compose-test.yml`, `docker-compose-prod.yml`). The files look like the following:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp.azurecr.io/myapp
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        PROFILE: int
    ports:
      - "8080:4200"
```

The followng is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine As builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

ARG PROFILE
ENV PROFILE $PROFILE
RUN echo "Environment: ${PROFILE}"
RUN npm run build-${PROFILE}

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/myapp/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Previously, when I had no environments, I was running the following commands only after the `npm install` in the dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But I have no way now to specify the environment with `npm start` so I have to build the application and run the built version (correct me if I am wrong). The thing is I am not really sure what I am doing in the second part of my new dockerfile when I use nginx alpine and if that brings my application up.

What should I do here? And what output should I expect when I run for example the following commands?

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-test.yml build
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-test.yml up
```

How can I run my application in the container with the chosen environment?

I have seen that some people - in addition to what I have done - put a `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

And add the following line to the dockerfile:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/.docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Do I need this file? What's the difference with my version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a port problem mainly.

In the `dockerfile` I have replaced the last lines with:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/myapp/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

There is no need to run `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`.

I have also created a `nginx.conf` file in my application (same folder of the `dockerfile`) with the following code:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Then in the `docker-compose.yml` file I have updated the port matching:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp.azurecr.io/myapp
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        PROFILE: int
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Now I can run multiple environments by using the docker-compose file I need. For example for int I use:

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-int.yml build
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-int.yml up
```

For test I use

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-test.yml build
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-test.yml up
```

Then I navigate to `localhost:8080` and my application runs correctly.